# How to count specific string using regex

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

I'm a newbie of using regex.

> How can I count specific letter on a string ?

var str = "FFFF000FFFCA";

i want an output of 4F303FCA.

> I used  `Regex.Replace(str, @"(.)\1*", m => m.Value.Length + m.Groups[1].Value);` but the output is :
>   4F303F1C1A

Thank you for helping.

Comment: That output looks right to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to output nothing when there is only one occurrence. You can use "conditional operator" (aka "ternary") to make that choice inline:

```
string input = "FFFF000FFFCA";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, 
    @"(.)\1*", m => 1 < m.Value.Length ? 
           m.Value.Length.ToString() + m.Groups[1].Value : m.Groups[1].Value);
```

Note something like `21` could not be decoded back (assuming you are trying to implement version of [Run-length encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding)).

Comment: I've added some water to your post so it is not such a dry code sample... Feel free to revert.

Comment: Thank you. That's what i want.

What if specific letter? Only letter "F".
Output is : 4F0003FCA.

thanks alot.